# Logging proper user ip behind a reverse proxy in GAE

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, winston, google-cloud-logging

I'm using cloudflare as a reverse proxy in front of AppEngine. Hence, in GCP Logging request log, the IP being logged is Cloudflare's.

Behind cloudflare, the actual user IP is `req.headers['x-forwarded-for'].split(',')[0]`, so I've been trying to work through [Google Logging](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-logging-winston) log correlation to get it right (in an express middleware):

```
const forwardedForHeader = req.headers['x-forwarded-for']
const userIp = forwardedForHeader ? forwardedForHeader.split(',')[0] : req.ip
res.on('finish', () => {
    logger.info(req.originalUrl, {
        httpRequest: {
            status: res.statusCode,
            requestUrl: req.originalUrl,
            requestMethod: req.method,
            remoteIp: userIp,
        },
        remoteIp: userIp, // workaround to get remote IP as metadata - GAE has everything else
    })
})
```

`LOGGING_SPAN_KEY` & `LOGGING_TRACE_KEY` are both set properly.

Unfortunately, I'm still getting 2 log entries (GAE generated 1 in request log; mine generated as above).

Is there any way to get the actual user ip in the request log ?

Comment: You can take a look into this article:
[How does Cloudflare handle HTTP Request headers?](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170986-How-does-Cloudflare-handle-HTTP-Request-headers-) >To restore original visitor IP addresses at your origin web server, Cloudflare recommends your logs or applications look at CF-Connecting-IP or True-Client-IP instead of X-Forwarded-For since CF-Connecting-IP and True-Client-IP have a consistent format containing only one IP. I hope this is useful.

Comment: Thanks for sharing ! It doesn't answer my question, since it's not going to fix the IP in GCP logs. Now it might help for pure application logging

Comment: Hello, 
As I understand you want GAE to log directly the user IP rather than Cloud Flare proxy IP into GCP logs. I want to tell you that you are doing the best approach which consists of creating this log directly with this information.
I want to tell you that what you want to do is infeasible since GAE has to log the IP which sends the request to Google infrastructure, otherwise the logs could be modified with other objectives. Since GAE has to log the IP who sends the request to Google Infrastructure, the approach that you use to log the user IP is the correct approach.